# High Resolution Screenshot

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, resolution, safari, screenshot

I am using the [Awesome Screenshot](http://awesomescreenshot.com) extension/addon for Google Chrome, Safari and Firefox.

It was working well and generating HiDPI (Retina Screenshot) on my MacBook Pro Retina until yesterday, but today it started generating normal screenshot in Firefox and Google Chrome yet still creates high resolution screenshots in Safari.

I am using Google Chrome Version: 38.0.2125.101 &  Firefox Version: 32.0.3.

How can I generate high resolution screenshots in Chrome and Firefox on my MacBook Pro which is Retina Ready?

Currently, I am using [Paparazzi](http://paparazzi.onfreedownload.com/) as an alternative for high resolution screenshots, but I need to take responsive screenshots as well by resizing the browser, which is not possible in Paparazzi.

Answer (score 15):

This can be achieved in Chrome as of v59:

[Announcement in the developer blog](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#screenshots)

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_6_9eFPhxI)

Summary of steps (if you prefer text):

1. Open Developer tools
2. Toggle the device toolbar
3. Set the desired resolution in the device toolbar (take note of the DPR option, as this is what controls pixel density)
4. Select the More options overflow menu in the device toolbar
5. Select Capture screenshot or Capture full size screenshot
6. The screenshot will be saved to your Downloads folder

Comment: A very useful answer. One note: To get higher screen resolutions just set the display pixel ratio (DPR) to some value greater than 1 (I used 4). Use any pixel size for height and width, but don't use too large values, instead increase the DRP to get a higher resolution. Note, that the resulting image size will be `height * width * DRP` pixels large.

Answer (score -2):

The extension "Nimbus Screen Capture" will work to do what you want.

For Firefox, it is available at: https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/nimbus-screenshot/

They also have a Chrome version, but I refuse to use Google products, so you're on your own for that one.